# Get the Identifier of the current tab - iphone

Tags: iphone, tabbarcontroller

Probably a simple question, but I'm having a hellofa time finding a solution to it.

I need to find the identifier of the current tab in a tabbarcontroller and use it in a conditional to run a method.

how do I find this?

```
if (self.tabbarcontroller.identifier == @"My identifier") {
   // do some method
} else {
   // do the default method
}
```

Comment: By identifier you mean the TabBarItem Identifier which can be "More", "Featured", "Top Rated" etc.

Comment: Correct, the tab bar that goes on the bottom of the view.

Comment: Is there any reason you are interested in the identifier and not the tag of the selected tab bar item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController*) window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *selectedVC = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
if ([selectedVC.identifier isEqualToString:@"anIdentifier"])
{
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

You can set the identifier of a ViewController in your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code. Also make sure that the delegate for the UITabBar is correct pointing to the view controller, in this case FirstViewController.

```
**FirstViewController.h****

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>

**FirstViewController.m:**

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[item tag]);
}
```